# Looping through PHP prepared SQL statement result twice

Tags: php, arrays, loops, mysqli, while-loop

I'm trying to loop through a SQL result in PHP twice, and I am not succeeding. I have tried to use mysqli data seek, but this does not work.

Here is what I have tried so far:

**my-new-file.php**

```
<?php
class myClass {
  function myFunction() {
    /*--Connection file for MySQL database. This file works fine.--*/
    include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "connection-files/mysqli-connect.php";

    if ($result = $mysqli->prepare($query)) {
      $result->execute();
      
      $result->bind_result($var1, $var2, $var3);
      
      /*============================================================*/
      /*====If I take out all of the code between the = signs, my second while statement works=====*/
      $myArray = array();

      while ($result->fetch()) {
        if (!in_array($var1, $myArray)) {
          array_push($myArray, $var1);
        }
      }
    
      /*--I thought the line below would reset looping through the query.--*/
      $result->data_seek(0);

      /*====If I take out all of the code between the = signs, my second while statement works=====*/
      /*============================================================*/

      /*--The second while statement is not echoing anything.--*/
      while ($result->fetch) {
        echo $var1;
      }
    }
  }
}

$newClass = new myClass;
$newClass->myFunction();
?>
```

If I do the code below, I get the desired result:

**my-newer-file.php**

```
<?php
[...All prior code from before...]
      while ($result->fetch()) {
        if (!in_array($var1, $myArray)) {
          array_push($myArray, $var1);
        }
      }
    
      /*--I thought the line below would reset looping through the query.--*/
      $result->data_seek(0);
      
      /*--Executing and binding the results again seems to get the second while statement to work, but running the execution statement twice seems inefficient.--*/
      $result->execute();
      $result->bind_result($var1, $var2, $var3);
      
      /*--This now works because of the above two lines--*/
      while ($result->fetch) {
        echo $var1;
      }
    }
  }
}
[...All prior code from before...]
?>
```

It seems like a waste of resources/inefficient to have to run the execute and bind_result statements twice. I was under the assumption that mysqli data seek would reset the pointer to 0, and I could loop through the query again.

This is probably just an oversight on my part. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you tryed to write `$result2=$result` before the first while statement and then use `$result2` in second while statement instead of `$result`?

Comment: Note the `while` loop! While there are results left, fetch them, when the loop is finished there are no more results to fetch, not even for a second loop, which you should never really need.

Comment: Why can't you accomplish this with 1 loop?

Comment: @Mathematician171 - Thanks for the input. That would still require me to run the result statement twice.

Comment: @adeneo - Thanks for the input. I understand how a while loop works, but my question was pertaining to why mysqli data seek will not restart the pointer to the first row in the SQL result, which is exactly what it is for.

Comment: @cmorrissey - Thanks for the input. I suppose I would be able to do this with one while loop. I would still like to know, however, why mysqi data seek is not working.

Comment: @aCarella Maybe it would be better to make a new question with that as the title.

Comment: Try to write  mysqli_data_seek($result, 0) rather than  $result->data_seek(0);

Comment: @BigScar - Thanks for the input. My current question reads "Looping through PHP prepared statement result twice", and mysqli data seek is the closest way I am aware of, as well as the most popular way via google results, to do this.

If you have a suggestion other than mysqli data seek to loop through SQL results twice, then I will gladly accept it in that this is the main focus of my question.

Comment: @anantkumarsingh - Thanks for the input. I cannot use that syntax in that my code is written in object-oriented style, while `mysqli_data_seek($result, 0)` is procedural style and the two are not compatible.

Comment: Wondering if you found a way to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `$result->store_result();`
right after the very first `$result->execute().`

Seemed to do the trick for me.